# Properties Class getProperty() internals

Tags: java, memory-management, properties, hashtable, getproperty

I have a huge file which contains lines in key=value format. 
If i wish to get the value of a particular key using getProperty() method of Properties class in java , is the complete file loaded into memory before the getProperty() operation is performed?

I have read that Properties class is a HashTable implementation java. So I would like to know if the entire properties file is loaded into a HashTable even to fetch the value of a single property using Properties Class.

Comment: Yes, the complete Table is loaded when you call the load method. The load method basically goes through each line and splits it using the '=' char and stores the value in front and behind the '=' in a Map.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR: The entire file is loaded into memory

[`java.util.Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) is not a `HashTable` implementation, it *is a* `HashTable`. i.e. it is an in-memory hash based lookup.

From the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Properties.java?av=f) you can see the implementation of `getProperty` simply delegates to `super.get` which is `HashTable.get`:

```
public String getProperty(String key) {
    Object oval = super.get(key);
    String sval = (oval instanceof String) ? (String)oval : null;
    return ((sval == null) && (defaults != null)) ? defaults.getProperty(key) : sval;
}
```

The `load` method reads the properties file (`.properties` or XML) into the `HashTable`.